# Combobox selecting error in silverlight 4.0

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

Here am using combobox(silverlight4.0) in a grid and setting the selection for combobox in XAML and passing the values as binding(Datacontext for grid) through the code.In my case am having two cascade combobox filling type,that is Department selection goes to team and managers list combobox which will filled in the department selection time only.

Now at this time when i select the team the managers list will shown perfectly and also changes happened in the managers list combobox with help of XAML code and when i changed the department the managres list and team list will be refreshed.

At this time if i select the team mangers list combobox is not getting selected.

Please help me for this.

Code is here:

This peice of code is manager combobox:

```
<ComboBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="1,15,0,15"Name="cboIndiaManagerTeamMaster" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=India_Manager,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="EmpId" DisplayMemberPath="EmployeeName"  />
```

Department Selection changed code:

```
private void cboDepartmentTeamMaster_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
cboIndiaManagerTeamMaster.ItemsSource = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides I understand that you implemented 3 (not 2) cascade lists I'm confuse with this: "At this time if I select the team managers list combobox is not getting selected.", not really sure what you mean.

Comment: When the department is changed i will get the new list of managers and team from the database and bind that list to the corresponding combobox and after that when i select the team the managers list is not getting selected,this is my error area and this means it is working  correctly for the first selection(Binding Itemsource for the first time) of the dept combobox.

Comment: Sorry but still confused... when you say "the managers list is not getting selected" you mean that it is not responding to mouse clicks? it does not have the focus?